# Krypton Components Textbox - How to Change Font Size and Textbox Size

Tags: vb.net, krypton-toolkit

Can anyone help me change the font of a textbox in my krypton ribbon control.  There is no simple property like there is for a windows control.  Looks like i may need to use the pallete control  can anyone help me!!! using VB.net

Answer (score 4):

You can do it from the properties window of the KryptonTextBox1 :

```
StateCommon => Content => Font
```